# How to access json value by key value in freemarker?

Tags: java, arrays, json, liferay, freemarker

Is there any way to access a `json` value by key value in freemarker? The json looks like this:

```
{"className":"Lorem Ipsum","classPK":"52293","title":"Test Name"}
```

I need these values to use them in a method:

```
localService.method(className, classPK);
```

I was trying to access them directly with `${json.getData()["classPK"]}`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use by using `${variableName.key}`. In Your case `<#assign data="Your JSON Goes here"?eval>` then after access using `${data.className}`.

Here Using `?eval` on String data which includes JSON ,we convert it to Freemarker littral.

For more information follow the links:- https://docs.akana.com/ag/processes/process_transform_freemarker.htm
https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/working-with-json-in-freemarker

Comment: Thanks. Now my problem is that `<#assign json = customField.getData() />` returns a json but access It by key doesnt work, but if I use directly `<#assign getData= {"className":"Lorem Ipsum","classPK":"52293","title":"Test Name"} >`  your answer  works. How to solve that?

Comment: From where you are getting customField object ??

Comment: From a template of a structure, It´s a field where you select a journal article, and with getData() it returns the json of the example.

Comment: Based on these, `getDate()` just returns a string. So, something had to parse it as JSON. FreeMarker 2.3.30 has no such function built in. (Some may will point out that `?eval` parses a string as FreeMarker expression, and most JSON is accidentally valid as such. But not when they contain `null`. Also, don't do that, as `?eval`-ing user specified content is a potential security backdoor, as FreeMarker expressions, unlike JSON, can call methods, and more.)

Comment: have you tried  ``<#assign json = customField.getData()?eval>`` to convert to json ?

Comment: It was the `?eval`. If you update your answer and explain how does `?eval` works I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @SilverSurfer FreeMarker 2.3.31 added `?eval_json`, use that. `?eval` is not good, as it can't parse `null`, and can call methods in the model, which can be a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use ?eval or the jsonFactoryUtil (if available). Examples:

```
<#assign customFieldJson = customField.getData()?eval />
${customFieldJson.className}
${customFieldJson.classPK}
${customFieldJson.title}
```

or

```
<#assign customFieldJson = jsonFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(customField.getData()) />
${customFieldJson.getString("className")}
${customFieldJson.getString("classPK")}
${customFieldJson.getString("title")}
```

I don't know which one is "better", but i prefer eval...

Answer (score 0):

Assign json into this variable and try to access this way

<#-- Freemarker hash from JSON literal -->
<#assign getData= {"className":"Lorem Ipsum","classPK":"52293","title":"Test Name"} >

${getData.className}

${getData.classPK}